# How to display different contents of different links to a particular area on home page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a  website for our organisation. In this website I wish to display contents from different links to a particular content area on home page. For example, suppose if a user clicks on "About Us" link then in that particular content area contents of "About Us" will be displayed and same case with the other links too. By default Contents of "Home" link will be displayed there. I have no idea how to achieve this....someone please help me!
(I am using Bootstrap,Html and Css. If other language is also needed for this purpose then please inform me that too.) Thank You all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link type="text/css"  href="design.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

                <div class="row" >

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Some Text...</div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-2" ></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8" >
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-inverse">

                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li> 
                        </ul>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-2" ></div>          
            </div>


        </nav>
    </div>
<div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" ></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Home</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">About Us</button>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">Main Content Area</div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>

            </div>
</div>
```

I wish to display all contents of links according to users choice in the 2nd div (from bottom).

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap you can set class "btn" in the tag "a" to get the same style of a button

```
<a href="#aboutus" class="btn btn-primary">About Us</a>
```

To display content acording of link you need set a "id" of tag "div" and the tag "a" set the name of the "id" in the "href=#aboutus" for example:

```
<div id="aboutus">
 <!-- content -->
</div>
<a href="#aboutus" class="btn btn-primary">About Us</a>
```